# Java scalability question

Tags: java, mysql, scalability

I am a Java developer, and I am finding a solution to scale my new application. I have the principal application like a directory of my clients and a lot of other "mini applications" with the same database/functionality but for different clients.

What is the best solution to scale my "mini applications" like a service for all clients?

Comment: Share the source code? Or share a service?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  How about an example?

Comment: What does the word "scale" mean to you?  How do you increase the number of entries in the database?  The number of simultaneous users you can handle?  "Scale" is such a generic, overused word - like "lightweight" - that means different things to different people.

Answer (score 2):

A typical layered architecture having

1. Presentation Layer
2. Business Logic Layer - Service Layer
3. Data Access layer

scales out pretty well. The layers shouldn't be dependent on each other and can remain on different machines. This allows very scalable architecture. We can have caching between the layers to boost performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Application Engine? (GAE) ;)

This easily allows you to scale to a large number of clients without you having to know in advance how many clients will be using your service.